# best way to monetize aws API gateway + lambda + rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-marketplace

selling an AWS API Gateway + lambda solution seems pretty straightforward as the customer is billed based on use.

In my case lambda writes data to an RDS DB which represents an hourly billed center of cost.

What would be a good way to fairly dispatch DB costs between different customers in such an application ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need a RDS DB for your customers? Or is it possible to store the data in DynamoDB? Than you could create for each customer `n` DynamoDB table(s) and they have to pay the provisoned read/write capacities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very open ended question.

Simplest from customer point of view is it course in form of cost to use YOUR service. I.e. you don't wanna show a component/line-item called AWS RDS in your customers' bills.

AWS RDS seems pretty flat rate model (per machine). So unless you're setting up separate instances for each of your customer, I see 2 choices:

- Flat tiered subscription. Where subscription gives you N free API calls.
- Flat tiered subscription + per API call. Where subscription just gets you on board or gives you N free API calls and you pay a la carte for rest.

E.g your tiers are small, medium & large with a cap on TPS (API calls or sec) of say 5, 10 and 100 for a price of $5, $7 and $30 per month.

Customers who cross TPS for their tier, automatically can be charged for next tier.

Of course you can come up with many other combinations.

Should also add that if you're setting up separate instances for each of your customer then the distribution is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Interesting. I could also create a separate instance for each customer (who would pay for the actual instance costs). The API gateway and lambda access would be charged per use. What do you think ?

Comment: @FredSullet depending on traffic per customer, it may or may not be economical. I would say it'll be pretty case specific. E.g. if you just have 3 customers with 100TPS each, then yes. If you have 100 customers with 3TPS each then may be not.